# Angular Custom Idle Timer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer

Hey guys currently i try to implement my own idle Timer. I thought of something like a service where you initialize the Global events. These reset the Timer. But with my current implementation there seems to be a context problem because i cant access the function with 'this'.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IdleService {

  constructor() {
           document.addEventListener("click", this.resetTimer, false);
   }

    public timeoutID:number;

     startTimer() {
        console.log("timer started");
        this.timeoutID =  setTimeout(() => {this.goInactive()}, 5000);
        console.log(this.timeoutID) 
    }

     resetTimer() {
        console.log(this.timeoutID);
        console.log("reset");
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
    }

     goOffline() {
            //alert("Hey");
            console.warn("goInactive");
            // this.logout();
    }


    }
```

App Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IdleService } from './idle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private idleService: IdleService){
       this.idleService.startTimer();
  }
  name = 'Angular 5';
}
```

if you got better ideas on how to solve this feel free to tell me. I know that Angular isnt really made for global events but i need this feature.

Here is also a Stackblitz if you want to play around with it a little bit.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-31ztnn?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is still interested. I moved the eventlistener to an observable and after that the context is right. But i would just recommend you to have a look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/idle-timer?embed=1&file=app/idle.service.ts).

if i have the really final answer i will post that here too.

Comment: do you have a final answer now?

Comment: at the end I used ng2-idle.. 
but i think i will do something more with this stackblitz because the library doesn't fit any use case